# Unable to reach ip from kubernetes pod but can access it from underlying server

Tags: kubernetes

I am able to hit the ip from the server on which the pod is running
wget https://10.64.2.21
-  https://10.64.2.21/
Connecting to 10.64.2.21:443... connected.

But not from within the pod 
➜  ~ k exec -ti debug /bin/sh
/ # wget https://10.64.2.21
Connecting to 10.64.2.21 (10.64.2.21:443)

^C
/ #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using this solution, which updated the iptables in each pod
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46170